# jsf fill table using repeat - special case

Tags: jsf, repeat

I get a List of object Computer, and I need to show the status (online or offline) of each one.
For example

---

Comp1:Online  | Comp2:Online  | Comp3:Online  | (Comp4:OffLine)

---

Comp6:Online  | Comp7:Offline | Comp8:Online  | (Comp9:Online )

---

Comp11:Online | Comp12:Online | Comp13:Online | (Comp14:OffLine)

---

In all the examples that I found, the table add one row for each object, so the
screen look like

Comp1:Online

---

Comp2:Online

---

Comp3:Online
.
.

---

Comp15:Online

Comment: I would suggest using a simple div for each comp and float that, so you get the layout you want.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing the loop inside `<h:panelGrid columns="4">` ?

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    Loop goes here
</h:panelGrid>
```